# Format buttons to fill parent based on dynamically added text

Tags: android, button, format, fill

I'm hoping I can get some formatting help.  I have a TableLayout.  Inside the TableRow, I have 2 RelativeLayouts.  Each RelativeLayout has 2 buttons in it that overlap (this is by design).  The button text is dynamically added at runtime.  This makes the buttons taller if the text is long enough.  However, the text in one column (RelativeLayout) is different that the text in other column (RelativeLayout).  So, the TableRow is expanded by the taller of the buttons.  What I'd like is to have the smaller buttons fill in to the same size as the larger one.

I'm real new to Android development, but I've tried every combination of match_parent/fill_parent/wrap_content that I can think of, but none of them make the buttons stay the same size (that is, the size of the larger one).  Some even expand the button to the full height of the screen (which I don't understand either...I'd think that the parent would be the TableRow and that would limit it)...

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I guess I wasn't clear.  I do not want to truncate any text.  I want the smaller buttons to expand in height to fill the space of the largest button in the row.

Comment: It seems a little sleep did the trick.  I've found that I was missing some formatting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
button.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
```

attribute while creating the buttons